# FP32 in Cuda on Matlab

Tags: matlab, gpu

I'm writing GPU code in Matlab but can't seem to access FP32, just FP64, and although the accuracy is better, we need to be able to get this to run quickly on consumer-grade Nvidia cards. I've read (https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/384854-are-calculations-on-a-gpu-using-the-parallel-computing-toolbox-in-matlab-r2017b-executed-with-double)that FP32 isn't accessible in Matlab to preserve accuracy, but was wondering if there was a way to access that functionality that doesn't involve using a pointer to split a double into two floats.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/measure-and-improve-gpu-performance.html#mw_1ffb4887-62d8-40cd-aaff-b694a85ccc62 clearly encourages the use of single precision to improve performance, so it must be possible

Comment: Isn't this just [`gpuArray`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/establish-arrays-on-a-gpu.html) ?

Comment: `a=gpuArray(single(rand(100)))`. I have no idea what else you need?